# Find the limit of $f_{n,k}(x)=(\cos(\pi n! x))^k$

Tags: real-analysis

I am having trouble to show that for each $x\in\mathbb{R}$
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\lim_{k\to\infty}f_{n,k}(x)=1_{\mathbb{Q}}(x)$$
for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$

I think that $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \cos(\pi n!x)$$ does not exist for all $x\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$. But raising it to the power of $k$ and taking limit seems to make the double limit exist here. Why does this happen here? Also, does it matter if I change the order of limit?

Comment: When $x$ is an integer, $\pi n! x$ is an even multiple of $\pi$ for all $n \geq 2$, so $\cos(\pi n! x)=1$ for $n \geq 2$ in this case. Something similar happens on the rationals: when $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, eventually $n! x$ becomes an integer, and soon thereafter it becomes an even integer, and thereafter the sequence is $1$. So the fact that the limit is $1$ on $\mathbb{Q}$ is easy. The limit being $0$ elsewhere is somewhat harder.

Comment: As for the limit being $0$ elsewhere, you just need to prove that $\pi n! x$ is never in $\pi \mathbb{Z}$ when $x \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Q}$. Then you will always be taking powers of something less than 1 in magnitude in the inner limit, so all of the inner limits will be zero. But that's not so hard to prove.

Comment: @Ian sorry it seems I am stealing the thunder with the same ideas, but I have been posting at the same times :L

Comment: @ellya No no, I didn't want to write out everything anyway. +1 to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly note that $n!$ is an even number for all $n\in\Bbb N:n\ge 2$, and so $n!\pi x$ is an even mutiple of $pi$, so we have $\cos(n!\pi x)=1$, and for $l\in\Bbb Q$, there is a large enough $n$ such that $n!l$ is an integer, and then again the we have the same result. Now for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, $n! x$ is always irrational for finite $n$, and so $n!\pi x$ is not any integer multiple of $\pi$ and $\cos(x)=\pm 1$ only at integer multiples of $\pi$, so for $x\in\Bbb R\setminus\Bbb Q$, $|\cos(n!\pi x)|^k\le\alpha^k$ where $\alpha\lt 1$, taking the limit in $k$ gives us zero.